# mongodb $group aggregation of string slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using the aggregation pipeline and after it quickly returns a match it gets slower on a sum if my source is a string. If it is an object or date it is super fast.

Here is my code:

```
feed.aggregate([
      {"$match": {"group_id": group.id , "date" : {"$gte": start_date, "$lte": end_date}}},
      {"$group": {"_id": {"source": "$source"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
    ])
```

If I do this I have no issues on speed.

```
feed.aggregate([
      {"$match": {"group_id": group.id , "date" : {"$gte": start_date, "$lte": end_date}}},
      {"$group": {"_id": {"source": "$date"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
    ])
```

Comment: Are these source strings big?

Comment: no very small like "twitter", "facebook"

Comment: How much slower? It's slower even with the same number of results in "`$source`" or "`$date`"?

Comment: how many distinct values are there in the two cases?  btw, why are you using an embedded document as _id?  just use _id:"$source" or _id:"$date"